# Dask - import dask_ml.cluster - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.cluster._k_means'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dask, dask-ml

I would like to use Dask to create a simple clustering model. **I have tried the following import statements individually (in separate cells)** in Jupyter Notebooks:

```
import dask_ml.cluster

from dask_ml.cluster import KMeans

from dask_ml.cluster import SpectralClustering
```

**Each of them separately** resulting in the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.cluster._k_means'
```

This seems really strange. Has anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

I encourage you to update Dask-ML to the latest release